# Using a subclass of a protocol requirement

Tags: swift, polymorphism, protocols, subclassing

I'm working on a project that's using MVVM and we'd like to introduce more safety by stopping the caller being able to mutate the objects we're exposing.

We can't make `Immutable` a `struct` and just mark `mutate()` as a `mutating`, because we add observers which mutates the object that we need in the `Immutable` form.

This example shows what we'd like to do, but we just get an error that `C` doesn't confirm to `P` because we're trying to satisfy the protocol with a subclass of the required `Immutable`, `Mutable`

```
class Immutable {}

class Mutable: Immutable {
    func mutate() {}
}
​
protocol P {
    var a: Immutable { get }
}
​
class C: P {
    let a: Mutable
​
    init() {
        a = Mutable()
        a.mutate()
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a creative solution to this that doesn't require lots of boilerplate to work around, like making a `Immutable` to satisfy the type requirements and then casting in line like:

```
class C: P {
    let a: Immutable
​
    init() {
        a = Mutable()
        (a as? Mutable)?.mutate()
    }
}
```

This isn't ideal for us because we call `mutate()` many, many times and don't want to have to refactor all of our code.

Comment: Making `Mutable` a subclass of `Immutable` seems like a conceptual issue. They shouldn't be related at all, since those two classes should actually be completely distinct from each other. A type should be either mutable or not, `Mutable` shouldn't inherit from `Immutable`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor It's a pretty common pattern throughout the history of Objective-C and Foundation.

Comment: @Tim and this is Swift, not Obj-C :) Obj-C patterns shouldn't blindly be brought into the world of Swift, since the two languages are fundamentally different in a lot of aspects

Comment: Yes they're different languages. But not sure what's indicating in this question that a pattern has been blindly brought across. If you've got a potential solution to the question asked, go for it, if not, it's not a particularly helpful contribution.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, just getting inspiration from types like `NSMutableParagraphStyle` and `NSMutableString`

Comment: @MikeB you shouldn't try to get inspiration from legacy Foundation types written in Objective-C before the idea of Swift was even born. It is important to know that a lot of Apple's codebase is written in Objective-C and shouldn't be considered as a good example when writing Swift code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `protocol` `P` to have an `associatedtype` as below,

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype T: Immutable
    var a: T { get set }
}
```

As you were assigning a value to variable `a` inside the `class` that conform to `P` so variable `a` declaration changed as above to allow setting a value.

Now, you can define the type inside the conforming `class` as,

```
class C: P  {
    var a: Mutable

    init() {
        self.a = Mutable()
        self.a.mutate()
    }
}
```